# Refering to this but not to extended class

Tags: java, inheritance

In a method, I would like to get the classname for a class which is extended by another.
But, if I call this method on the child, I have this child's name.

How can I refer to the class where the method is written? Not to the extended class.

Comment: this is not what I want to do. In the parent class, I want to get the classname of THIS class. But when I do this.getClass() and I extend this class, it refers to the child class.

Comment: Don't edit your questions to include things like "Resolved" in the name as such erroneous forum conventions are not useful on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a class like

```
public class A {
}
```

You can reference the defining class by using `A` (the class name). E.g.

```
public void do() {
    System.out.println("Defined in " + A.class.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you want to get the super-class's name.

**using Reflection API:**

```
  Class subclass = o.getClass();
  Class superclass = subclass.getSuperclass();
  String className = superclass.getName();
```

Comment: this is not what I want to do. In the parent class, I want to get the classname of THIS class. But when I do this.getClass() and I extend this class, it refers to the child class.